# Simulating a Windows XP Screensaver in R

Tags: r

Using the R programming language, I am trying to simulate the (random) movement of a small box bouncing around a larger box, until the first time it collides with a boundary (similar to a Windows XP Screensaver):

https://i.imgur.com/JdwSFCs.gif

I tried to do this as follows:

- Imagine a 8x8 grid (larger box)
- There is a 3x3 (small box) which has its center located at the position (4,4) at time=0
- At each second, there is an equal probability that the center of the small box can move 1 unit in any direction
- This continues until one of its edges first makes contact with any of the boundaries of the larger box for the first time

Here is the logic I am using:

**Step 1:** First, I created an empty data frame to store the results of the simulation and initialized the small box

```
centre <- c(4, 4)

movement_df <- data.frame(iteration = integer(), 
                          top_left = character(), 
                          bottom_left = character(), 
                          top_right = character(), 
                          bottom_right = character(), 
                          centre = character())
```

**Step 2:** Next, I tried to write a function to randomly move the small box around the larger box:

```
move_small_box <- function(centre, iteration, movement_df) {

  movement_df[nrow(movement_df) + 1, ] <- c(iteration, 
                                            paste(centre[1] - 1, centre[2] - 1, sep = ","), 
                                            paste(centre[1] + 1, centre[2] - 1, sep = ","), 
                                            paste(centre[1] - 1, centre[2] + 1, sep = ","), 
                                            paste(centre[1] + 1, centre[2] + 1, sep = ","), 
                                            paste(centre[1], centre[2], sep = ","))
  

  direction <- sample(c("up", "down", "left", "right"), 1)
  

  if (direction == "up") {
    centre[2] <- centre[2] - 1
  } else if (direction == "down") {
    centre[2] <- centre[2] + 1
  } else if (direction == "left") {
    centre[1] <- centre[1] - 1
  } else if (direction == "right") {
    centre[1] <- centre[1] + 1
  }
  
  return(list(centre, movement_df))
}
```

**Step 3:** Finally, I simulated 100 iterations of the small box moving

```
for (iteration in 1:100) {
  result <- move_small_box(centre, iteration, movement_df)
  centre <- result[[1]]
  movement_df <- result[[2]]
}

print(movement_df)

    iteration top_left bottom_left top_right bottom_right centre
1           1      3,3         5,3       3,5          5,5    4,4
2           2      2,3         4,3       2,5          4,5    3,4
3           3      1,3         3,3       1,5          3,5    2,4
4           4      0,3         2,3       0,5          2,5    1,4
5           5      1,3         3,3       1,5          3,5    2,4
6           6      1,2         3,2       1,4          3,4    2,3
7           7      2,2         4,2       2,4          4,4    3,3
```

**My Question:** I am not sure as to how I can stop the simulation at the first moment when a collision occurs with the boundary? Can someone please show me how to do this?

**Notes:** Visualizations of the box trajectory:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)



movement_df$bottom_left_x <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(movement_df$bottom_left, ","), "[", 1))
movement_df$bottom_left_y <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(movement_df$bottom_left, ","), "[", 2))
movement_df$bottom_right_x <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(movement_df$bottom_right, ","), "[", 1))
movement_df$bottom_right_y <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(movement_df$bottom_right, ","), "[", 2))
movement_df$top_left_x <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(movement_df$top_left, ","), "[", 1))
movement_df$top_left_y <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(movement_df$top_left, ","), "[", 2))
movement_df$top_right_x <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(movement_df$top_right, ","), "[", 1))
movement_df$top_right_y <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(movement_df$top_right, ","), "[", 2))


movement_df$centre_x <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(movement_df$centre, ","), "[", 1))
movement_df$centre_y <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(movement_df$centre, ","), "[", 2))

ggplot(movement_df, aes(x = centre_x, y = centre_y)) +
    geom_path() +
    geom_text(aes(label = iteration), position = position_jitter(width = 0.35, height = 0.35)) + # Add jitter to the numbers
    labs(x = "X Coordinate", y = "Y Coordinate", title = "Trajectory of the Centre of the Box") +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```
plot_x <- ggplot(movement_df, aes(x = iteration)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = bottom_left_x, color = "bottom_left"), group = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(y = bottom_right_x, color = "bottom_right"), group = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(y = top_left_x, color = "top_left"), group = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(y = top_right_x, color = "top_right"), group = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(y = centre_x, color = "centre"), group = 1) +
    labs(x = "Iteration", y = "X Coordinate", color = "Position", title = "X Coordinates of the Small Box") +
    theme_minimal()

plot_y <- ggplot(movement_df, aes(x = iteration)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = bottom_left_y, color = "bottom_left"), group = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(y = bottom_right_y, color = "bottom_right"), group = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(y = top_left_y, color = "top_left"), group = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(y = top_right_y, color = "top_right"), group = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(y = centre_y, color = "centre"), group = 1) +
    labs(x = "Iteration", y = "Y Coordinate", color = "Position", title = "Y Coordinates of the Small Box") +
    theme_minimal()
grid.arrange(plot_x, plot_y, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to break the loop once there is a collision. Using the `break` keyword you can finish the loop prematurely.

For example:

```
# You need to evaluate if a collision exists
# (e.g. the limit of the inner box are equal or outside the limits of the outer box.)
isCollision <- function(centre) {
  upperBound <- 8
  lowerBound <- 0
  innerBoxSize <-1.5
  if (centre[1] + innerBoxSize >= upperBound) return(TRUE)
  if (centre[1] - innerBoxSize <= lowerBound) return(TRUE)
  if (centre[2] + innerBoxSize >= upperBound) return(TRUE)
  if (centre[2] - innerBoxSize <= lowerBound) return(TRUE)
  return(FALSE)
}

for (iteration in 1:100) {
  result <- move_small_box(centre, iteration, movement_df)
  centre <- result[[1]]
  movement_df <- result[[2]]
  # First you must check if there is a collision 
  if (isCollision(centre)) {
    # If there is, this breaks the loop
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: @ Jfloresl: thank you so much! does the rest of my code look correct?